# pull out sequence from genbank formt

Tags: perl, bioinformatics, bioperl, genbank

This code was working properly but now it complains, does the genbank structure changed?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w                                                                                                                                                                 
#use strinct ;                                                                                                                                                                     

use Bio::SeqIO;
use Bio::Seq;
use Bio::DB::EUtilities;


    @refSeqIDs=qw(NC_000915.1 NC_017379.1 NC_017371.1 NC_017354.1);
    foreach my $refSeqIDs (@refSeqIDs){
        my $factory = Bio::DB::EUtilities->new(-eutil   => 'efetch',-db=> 'protein',-  rettype => 'gb',
                                           -email   => 'x@y.com',-id=> $refSeqIDs);
        my $rawfile = "$refSeqIDs.gbk";
        $factory->get_Response(-file =>"$refSeqIDs.gbk");
        my $seqio_object = Bio::SeqIO->new(-format=>"Genbank",-file =>"$refSeqIDs.gbk");
        while ( my $seq_object=$seqio_object->next_seq){
            $sequence=$seq_object->seq;
            print ("$sequence\n");
        }
    }
```

Comment: In which way does it complain?

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 0):

Your `$sequence` variable is empty because there are no sequences in these genbank records. If you just want to download the full genome sequences for these IDs, just specify that you want a fasta instead of a genbank record.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::DB::EUtilities;


my @refSeqIDs = qw(NC_000915.1 NC_017379.1 NC_017371.1 NC_017354.1);

my $factory = Bio::DB::EUtilities->new(-eutil   => 'efetch', 
                                       -db      => 'nucleotide', 
                                       -rettype => 'fasta',
                                       -email   => 'x@y.com',
                                       -id      => \@refSeqIDs);

print $factory->get_Response->content;
```

If you wanted something different, please indicate what you were trying to fetch. Also, it is good to always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of your script for diagnosing these types of messages.